# CoffeeScript style initialization didn't make it to Ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, initialization

From [this blog post](http://kresimirbojcic.com/2012/08/23/things-to-look-forward-to-in-ruby-2-dot-0.html) and various other news and podcasts, I was under the impression that CoffeeScript style class initialization was coming to Ruby 2.0. However, trying out the example from the blog post

```
class FooBar
  def initialize(@name, @last_name)
    #nice isn't it?
  end

  def to_s
    "#@name #@last_name"
  end
end
```

Creates a syntax error

```
test.rb:2: formal argument cannot be an instance variable
  def initialize(@name, @last_name)
                      ^
test.rb:2: formal argument cannot be an instance variable
  def initialize(@name, @last_name)
                                  ^
```

Did this feature never make it to Ruby 2.0? I haven't found any news or announcements that this is getting removed.

Comment: It's not a feature of Ruby 2.0 nor was it part of 1.8.7. You would do better to rely on the official Ruby release documents at http://www.ruby-lang.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been proposed in Ruby Core as feature [#5825](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5825) or as  [#8563](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8563). It has never been decided that it will become a feature. See the discussion there.

Comment: It's really too bad, the CoffeeScript way is far DRYer.